# Get the first thumbnail in WooCommerce

Tags: image, wordpress, thumbnails, woocommerce

Is it possible to just get the first thumbnail, even if there's more attatched?

This is WooCommerce' code to get the thumbnails:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product Thumbnails
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.3
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $post, $product, $woocommerce;

$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

if ( $attachment_ids ) {
    ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">

    <ul class="large-block-grid-4 thumbnails">

    <?php

        $loop = 0;
        $columns = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', 3 );

        foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {

            $classes = array( 'zoom' );

            if ( $loop == 0 || $loop % $columns == 0 )
                $classes[] = 'first';

            if ( ( $loop + 1 ) % $columns == 0 )
                $classes[] = 'last';

            $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

            if ( ! $image_link )
                continue;

            $image       = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, apply_filters( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_thumbnail' ) );
            $image_class = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $classes ) );
            $image_title = esc_attr( get_the_title( $attachment_id ) );

            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '<li><a href="%s" class="%s" title="%s"  rel="slb prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">%s</a></li>', $image_link, $image_class, $image_title, $image ), $attachment_id, $post->ID, $image_class );

            $loop++;
        }

    ?>

    </ul>

    </div>
    </div>

    <?php
} ?>
```

I already found a solution to hide all thumbnails with css, but I like to keep my code clean. So I prefer to do this with WooCommerce.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like;

```
<?php 
$attachment_id = 8; // attachment ID

$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id ); // returns an array
if( $image_attributes ) {
?> 
<img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```